# amazonS3client.SelectObjectContentAsync - downloading the large jsonline formate file - unwanted line break

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

I am trying to download a file content from the S3 bucket using the SelectObjectContentAsync method from AWSSDK for C#.
But there are some unwanted line break(\n) in mid of the raw data.
Data Example :

> {"Id":1,"Name":"aaa"},  {"Id":2,"N 
>   \name":"bbb"}

My Code :

```
var amazonS3Client = new AmazonS3Client(awsAccessKeyId, awsSecretAccessKey, region);
                SelectObjectContentRequest selectObjectContentRequest = new SelectObjectContentRequest()
                {
                    Bucket = bucketName,
                    Key = key,
                    ExpressionType = ExpressionType.SQL,
                    Expression = query,
                    InputSerialization = new InputSerialization()
                    {
                        JSON = new JSONInput()
                        {
                            JsonType = JsonType.Lines
                        },
                        CompressionType = CompressionType.Gzip
                    },
                    OutputSerialization = new OutputSerialization()
                    {
                        JSON = new JSONOutput()
                        {
                            RecordDelimiter = ","
                        }
                    }
                };
                using (var content = amazonS3Client.SelectObjectContentAsync(selectObjectContentRequest).Result.Payload)
                {
                    foreach (var item in content)
                    {
                        if (item is RecordsEvent recordsEvent)
                        {
                            using (var reader = new StreamReader(recordsEvent.Payload, Encoding.UTF8))
                            {
                                using (var file = new StreamWriter(path, true))
                                {
                                    file.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Could you add some more information? What exactly are you trying to do, and what is failing? You wrote you have a unwanted line breaks in a file and pasted some code - that's not a question.

Comment: I'm downloading the large file content from the s3 bucket and deserializing it to the object. The file contains the data in Json Line format. In mid of the content, One json obejct is splitted in to two lines. So im getting invalid json object exception when deserializing it.

Comment: Are you getting an error back from S3, or are you experiencing an exception thrown in your application? Where exactly are you doing the serialization? There isn't any in the code you shared.

Comment: Mistake is from my code, the content was sent in different chunk and I deserializing it before it gets the full content. So it throws the error. Thanks for your response